# HTML5 .ogv video file not loading in Firefox

Tags: firefox, html, video

I have an .ogv file set up at [removed link]

I've tested playing it directly in Chrome and it plays fine. However in Firefox (3.6x) it only shows the loading circle animation. Upon checking Firebug I see that Firefox keeps downloading parts of the file, then starting again.

I've check the MIME type via curl and it is delivering the proper video/ogv.

Any ideas about why this might be happening?

Comment: I did find this one similar issue on the Firefox support forum, but no answers there as of yet.
http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/777738

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. The issue was due to having gzip enable on my server. Firefox cannot handle ogv requests properly if gzip is enabled.